# How to find a file with name = X in a SPList

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, splistitem, linq, splist

Looking for recommendations.  Have a file in a document library with name x.txt.    In a workflow code behind, I need to get the file to read its contents.  What is the best/most efficient way to do this?  Was thinking a linq query on the SPList.Item collection but might be off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you have the list, you could get your item like this

```
var myItem = myList.Items.Cast<SPListItem>().Where(n => n.File.Name == "x.txt").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: - 1. Although this satisfies the question, there could be serious performance ramifications. Using CAML is the way to go.

Comment: I agree, the other answer is better in most cases

Answer (score 11):

If you use linq to object, you always retrieve ALL records from DB. It is not good if you have got a lot of data. To reduce records you can use CAML query:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();    
query.Query = "<Where>" +
                    "<Eq>" +
                         "<FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\"/>" +
                         "<Value Type=\"Text\">" + fileName + "</Value>" +
                    "</Eq>" +
                "</Where>";
SPListItem item = list.GetItems(query).FirstOrDefault();
```

In this case items are selected from DB by query and then you can get first item.

Comment: Hi, FileLeafRef will trigger listview threshold issues.